# openweathermap api invalid api key error [error401]

Tags: javascript, openweathermap

I am facing a problem dealing with openweathermap api, the api call is working perfectly in the browser but when use it in the project I get error401 which is referred here like this:
[image]

I have none of the problems listed in it

also here's the link:http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=10001,us&appid=####

works perfectly in the browser

[image]

and here's my app.js:

```
/* Global Variables */
let baseURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=';
let apiKey = ',us&appid=####';



// Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
let d = new Date();
let newDate = d.getMonth()+'.'+ d.getDate()+'.'+ d.getFullYear();

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

function performAction(e){
  const temperature =  document.getElementById('zip').value;
  const userResponse = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
  console.log(baseURL+temperature+apiKey)
  const getTemp = async (baseURL,temperature,apiKey)=>{
      
      const res = await fetch(baseURL+temperature+apiKey)
    try {

    const data=await res.json();
    return data;
    
    }  catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
     }
  }
   getTemp(baseURL+temperature+apiKey).then( res =>{ console.log(res);
   
    postData('/add', {temperature: temperature, date: newDate, userResponse: userResponse});
    updateUI('/all');})
```

when I console.log() the url it works perfectly, yet the error appears in the get request:
[image]

Comment: Tell me you didn’t share your private key.

Comment: not sure what you mean but if the limit is exceeded we get another error

Comment: @emix we get error 429

Comment: ok.. basically what he's saying is.. the api key u were given isn't something u shud put up here.. I SUGGEST U CHANGE IT cuz not everyone has hearts like us

Comment: I know it's been two years but I checked and that API key you retracted is still enabled. Please log in to your OWM account and disable that old key... I'll also be sending an email to OWM to have them disable it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getTemp` is the problem

the first argument given to `getTemp` is the full url (yet the function combines 3 arguments for the fetch url)

2 of these values therefore will be undefined and the fetch would end up as `(baseURL+temperature+apiKey)+undefined+undefined` instead of `baseURL+temperature+apiKey`

The solution is for when calling `getTemp`, use commas so that they fill their appropriate argument places in the function

```
/* Global Variables */
let baseURL = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=';
let apiKey = ',us&appid=####';



// Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
let d = new Date();
let newDate = d.getMonth()+'.'+ d.getDate()+'.'+ d.getFullYear();

document.getElementById('generate').addEventListener('click', performAction);

function performAction(e){
  const temperature =  document.getElementById('zip').value;
  const userResponse = document.getElementById('feelings').value;
  console.log(baseURL+temperature+apiKey)
  const getTemp = async (baseURL,temperature,apiKey)=>{
      
      const res = await fetch(baseURL+temperature+apiKey)
    try {

    const data=await res.json();
    return data;
    
    }  catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
    // appropriately handle the error
     }
  }
   getTemp(baseURL,temperature,apiKey).then( res =>{ console.log(res);
   
    postData('/add', {temperature: temperature, date: newDate, userResponse: userResponse});
    updateUI('/all');})
```

Comment: I saw the undefined+undefined and I couldn't understand the reason, this works now thank you so much!

Comment: @TheBombSquad plz remove the api key

Comment: I didn't ask the question @TheBombSquad

Comment: @TheBombSquad I don't think it's that obvious